# Exponential Decay Surrounding Bounding Box

Tags: c#, gaussian, exponential

I didn't really know how to phrase this question, its quite strange.

I have a 1d array of intensity values, and a bounding box (integer start and end point in the array). I want to keep the values within the bounding box the same, but diminish the values outside the box in an exponential way (ie the further away they are the more they are diminished). Should look something like a gaussian with a plateau where the bounding box is. Can anyone give an example of how I could do this? My brain is not working right tonight, thanks.

UPDATE:

I used this:

```
if (j < low) a[j] *= Logistic(t*(j + (6f/t) - low));
else if (j > high) a[j] *= Logistic(-t*(j - (6f/t) - high));

private double Logistic(double x)
{
    return (1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-x)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
if (n<low)
  a[n] *=  exp(-t*(low-n));
else if (n>high)
  a[n] *=  exp(-t*(n-high));
else 
  a[n] *=  1.0;
```

with a parameter t? Indeed the last else branch may be omitted.

Comment: I would take off the last branch, waste of cycles

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to *decrease* exponentially, getting arbitrarily close to 0?

```
value = 1 / e^(distance)
```

or something which increases fast at first and slowly as you move further out ie. the inverse of the exponential?

```
value = ln(distance)
```

---

If you want something similar to that (increases fast at first, slowly as you get further out) that is **bounded**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067019/convert-arbitrary-length-to-a-value-between-1-0-a-1-0/3071578#3071578) on sigmoid curves.

Comment: @BluRaja I think something like that linked answer would be better actually, how could I stretch and time shift the `2/(1+e^-x) - 1 `function?

Comment: @Chimoo: Same way you stretch and shift every function:  multiply `x` to stretch *(well, actually compress; you'd divide to stretch)*, add to `x` to shift.  `value = 2/(1+e^(x/stretch + shift)) - 1`  *- PS. If you use this, don't forget to change the accepted answer ;)*

Comment: Thanks, I already got the answer from math.stackexchange :P I used a combination of both so I'll just leave it, posted up what my final code was

Answer (score 0):

You want to chop off the hump of the Gaussian, essentially?

The Gaussian is something like `I = I_0 exp(-aX^2)`.  You have `I` at `X` at half the width of your bounding box.  Then you can play with `I_0` and `a` until you get what you want (choose an `I_0` to get the corresponding `a`, or vice versa).

(Also, `X` is offset to the center of your bounding box.  The above formula works for `X` = 0.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this one, I did say my brain was fried tonight :P sorry @John thanks for the answer though

Comment: The other answers will probably be close enough for what you want.  This answer describes how to get to a "gaussian with a plateau where the bounding box is" in the strict sense: It's a gaussian with a plateau where the bounding box is.  If you really just need something that decays, then the other answers will do just fine for you.